# Building wxPython 4.1.1 using gtk4 instead of gtk3 when installing it with pip

Tags: python, pip, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

The Python apt-package called `python3-wxgtk4.0` on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, as its name says, is probably build with gtk4:

```
$ apt-cache policy python3-wxgtk4.0 

python3-wxgtk4.0:
  Installed: 4.0.7+dfsg-13build1
  Candidate: 4.0.7+dfsg-13build1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.7+dfsg-13build1 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But the version of this package, `4.0.7`, os too old for some usage.

And when trying to install a more up-to-date version with `pip`, it seems that wxWidgets automagically compiles with gkt3:

```
$ pip3 --verbose install wxPython==4.1.1

Using pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Collecting wxPython==4.1.1
  Using cached wxPython-4.1.1.tar.gz (66.0 MB)
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
    warnings.warn(
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
    warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:317: DistDeprecationWarning: use_2to3 is ignored.
    warnings.warn(f"{attr} is ignored.", DistDeprecationWarning)
  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/sphinx/build'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git' found under directory 'wx'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'wx'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory 'wx'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7naa9j1r/wxPython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (1.23.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: wxPython
  Running command python setup.py bdist_wheel
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
    warnings.warn(
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
    warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:317: DistDeprecationWarning: use_2to3 is ignored.
    warnings.warn(f"{attr} is ignored.", DistDeprecationWarning)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
  generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly
  to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use
  --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
  message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

  "/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build
  Will build using: "/usr/bin/python3"
  3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0]
  Python's architecture is 64bit
  cfg.VERSION: 4.1.1

  Running command: build
  Running command: build_wx
  wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode', '--gtk3']
  Configure options: ['--enable-unicode', '--with-gtk=3', '--enable-sound', '--enable-graphics_ctx', '--enable-display', '--enable-geometry', '--enable-debug_flag', '--enable-optimise', '--disable-debugreport', '--enable-uiactionsim', '--enable-autoidman', '--with-sdl']
  /tmp/pip-install-e18fhds7/wxpython_2fcd6d486f1646cbac69c59578dd763b/ext/wxWidgets/configure --enable-unicode --with-gtk=3 --enable-sound --enable-graphics_ctx --enable-display --enable-geometry --enable-debug_flag --enable-optimise --disable-debugreport --enable-uiactionsim --enable-autoidman --with-sdl
  checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  checking for toolkit... gtk
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  (...many other checks)
```

I'm curious, hence my question; is it possible to tell pip to fetch `wxPython==4.1.1` and to compile it using gtk4 instead of gtk3? If this ever makes sense of course.

Aside note:

The latest `wxPython 4.2.0` is unfortunately buggy during the install with pip on Ubuntu 22.04.1:

```
$ pip3 install -U wxPython

Requirement already satisfied: wxPython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (4.0.7)
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-a9emvjpo/wxpython_892c7b008de74c9db8d68d1c5c97e8a5/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
        File "/tmp/pip-install-a9emvjpo/wxpython_892c7b008de74c9db8d68d1c5c97e8a5/buildtools/config.py", line 30, in <module>
          from attrdict import AttrDict
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/attrdict/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from attrdict.mapping import AttrMap
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/attrdict/mapping.py", line 4, in <module>
          from collections import Mapping
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: it doesn't build with GTK4 - it builds with GTK3. The `4` heer is the wxPython version. wxWidgets (and wxPython) does npot support GTK4 (yet) - see the recent thread in the wxWidgets ML.